# Count the number of occurences of a key in a json object - IMPALA/HIVE

Tags: sql, json, hive, impala

I have a column in my Impala Table which is a map<string,string>. I have extracted that column as a key and value pair in 2 different cols as shown below.
The value column is a json object. I have to find out whether there are multiple occurrences of a particular key in that value column for a particular id.

```
id   |  key    |   value

1    | brm_res  | {'abc':'3rr','vbg':''r45','abc':'5rr'}

2    | brm_res  | {'abc':'3rr','vbg':''r45','bgh':'5rr'}

3    | brm_res  | {'abc':'3rr','vbg':''r45','tyu':'5rr'}

4    | brm_res  | {'abc':'3rr','vbg':''r45','yuo':'5rr'}
```

**As shown in the example above, for a particular id(id=1) and key(brm_res), there are 2 entries for  (abc) key in the value column. How to find this.**

Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate character length of initial string, remove all occurences of key, calculate the difference in length, divide by length of key, it will be the number of occurrences. Something like this (not tested):

```
(char_length(value)-char_length(replace(value, "\'abc\':", ''))) div char_length("\'abc\':");
```

Comment: This may work and we can use `length()` as well. But is OP wanted to know how many times a certain key column occurs  and `abc` is just an example  and it can be anything.

Comment: @KoushikRoy yes, this expression returns how many times  a certain key column occurs, and instead of `abc` something else can be used